# How do I create a post_id column, for admin posts list?

Tags: admin

I'm trying to add a column to display the post_id from the wp_postmeta table. I would like to display it in the admin posts list. Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-movie_reviews_columns', 'my_columns' ); 
function my_columns ( $columns ) {
  global $post;
  $columns['id'] = 'ID';  
  return $columns;
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'populate_columns' );
function populate_columns( $column ) {
  if ($column == 'id'){
    echo $post_id;
  }
}
```

The ID column is visible, but no post_id are in that column- it is just blank. Please can you suggest changes. I'm new to wordpress development so please be gentle.

Comment: Well, you have curly quotes in the code. Other than that, what isn't working exactly? Please check the "Related" questions to the right -->

Comment: Thanks! I have corrected the curly quotes in  ($column == ‘id’){  The post_id's aren't showing in the column, the column is just blank. There should be the post_ids here.

Comment: where does $post_id come from?

Comment: @Milo Thanks for taking an interest! I now know that $post_id was wrong. I have changed the code for the correct code ( hope that is allowed on stackexchange). Please can you explain it? I'm new to wordpress development & confused by it. Thanks-again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set `$post_id` so there is no reason is should display. If you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) as you should when you are working, you would have spotted the error immediately.

What you need to do is:

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'populate_columns' );
function populate_columns( $column ) {
  global $post;
  if ($column == 'id'){
    echo $post->ID;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you @s_ha_dum , I will use your code as it makes it much simpler than the code (now above) that I've found on the internet. Thanks-again!

Comment: Thanks everyone. @S_ha_dum 's code provides the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Please mark this as the "accepted" solution if it solved the problem.